# library not found for -lxml2 Only when running on Device, not Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am unable to compile the application and put it on a device because of the following error:
library not found for -lxml2

I have already included the proper header search paths in the build settings.  I am able to run on simulator but am not able to run on a device.  I am using iOS7 on the device and the application is built targeting iOS7 using xcode 5.  Has anyone encountered a situation such as this?  I did a substantial amount of testing and only found suggestions about the header search path.  Thanks.

Comment: So you set the *Header Search Path*, which affects compilation, but how about the *Library Search Path*, which affects linking?

Comment: No it was not set.  I am using kissxml which requires libxml2.  They did not mention the library search paths.  I did just set those to try it though and still get the error, I set them to $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 does that sound right to you?

Comment: Kris, did you have any luck solving this problem? I'm struggling with it right now.

Comment: please update if any one has resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

- For your project target, select "Build Phases" tab
- Under "Link Binary With Libraries", click "+"
- In the dialog, search "xml" and select "livxml2.dylib" from the result
- Click "Add"
- Build your application